# magento 1.7.0.2 - one product - different size - available

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, product

I got in my shop product (simple product). This product have X price and got five size available. If customer choice bigger size price going up. That i know how must to do. But how to do this:

Product size1 - available 1qty
Product size2 - available 3qty
Product size3 - available 0qty
product size4 - available 4qty
Product size5 - available 2qty

In product options (inventory) i have Qty-10. But this is for product not for size.

Anyone can explain me what I must to do step by step.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you want to manage inventory of child product then you need to make configurable products. all child product add with one create one configurable product. If you go with product custom option you can not manage inventory by child product.